# Permission are insufficient after Migrating SSRS from Native mode to SharePoint 2013 Integration Mode

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

I have some SSRS reports which are in native mode on reporting server. The reports have 2 kinds of data sources: database connection and report model. I can run/view the report using my account directly without problem. Now, I migrate the reports to sharepoint 2013 integration mode (SP is installed on another server).

If the report uses database connection as data source, it works fine after migration as long as I change it uses stored credentials which is fine. However, if the report uses both database connection AND report models, when I view the report from SP site, it always says:

The permissions granted to user '.....' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)

The account login the SP site is the same as I use to view the report on database server.

Anyone had similar situation? Or, migrated SSRS (using report model) to Sp 2013 successfully?

thanks